# How to print times (hh:mm) in a quarter-hour cycle?

Tags: java, time

I need to basically print every quarter-hour of the day from 00:00 to 23:45 (so 96 different times) in hh:mm format to create a html report.  Is there a standard library to do that? Or another way?

```
PrintStream fillStatus = new PrintStream("Report.html");
            for (int(int i=0; i <= 116; i++) {
                jobStatus[] = FileMonitorLog.getStatusOfJob(i) 
                            
                        
                fillStatus.println("<tr >");
                fillStatus.println("<td>"+hh:mmTime+"</td>");
                
                for (quarter=0; quarter <= 96; quarter++) {
                    fillStatus.println("<td>"+getHtmlStatus(jobStatus[quarter])."</td>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done using the `java.time.LocalTime`:

```java
var time = LocalTime.MIN;
do {
    System.out.println(time);
    time = time.plusMinutes(15);
} while (!time.equals(LocalTime.MIN));
```

It can also be done with a `for` loop, just consider that `LocalTime` does not accept `24:00`, so `23:45 + 0:15` results in `00:00`.

---

The default format used by `LocalTime.toString()` is `HH:MM` if seconds and fraction of seconds is zero. A `DateTimeFormat` can be used to format the tine using a different format.

Comment: I had to replace "var" with "LocalTime" but it worked thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about an official way, but two for loops are pretty quick about it.

You could of course do a lot of complicated things with a date and time library, but why make it difficult when it can be done easily?

See it online: https://ideone.com/swFbz2

```java
        String[] quarters = {"00", "15", "30", "45"};
        ArrayList<String> hours = new ArrayList<>(24*4);
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                hours.add((i < 10 ? "0" + i : i) + ":" + quarters[j]);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i <= 10; i++) {
 
                output.add("<tr >");
                output.add("  <td>thingy/td>");
 
                for (int quarter=0; quarter < 24*4; quarter++) {
                    output.add("  <td>"+hours.get(quarter)+" jobstatus is perfectly fine.... believe me.</td>");
                }
                output.add("</tr>");
        }
        //System.out.println(String.join("\n",hours));
        System.out.println(String.join("\n", output));
```